# "If you go out to war against your enemies"; why are they called our enemies?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, rashi, ki-teitzei, deuteronomy

*Ki Teze* begins, "if you go out to war against your enemies" ([Devarim 21:10](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9985#v=10)). RaSh"I states:

> **כי תצא למלחמה**: במלחמת הרשות הכתוב מדבר
>
> **If you go out to war**: The verse refers to a non-obligatory [LF: rather than obligatory] war

If `Am Yisra'el wages voluntary war (albeit after offering peaceful subservience to `Am Yisra'el to the other nation; see [Devarim 20:10-15](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9984#v=10)), why would those nations who refuse peaceful subservience be considered our enemies? It was `Am Yisra'el who instigated!

Comment: They're enemies because they're the people we're fighting against...

Comment: @Salmononius2 We're only fighting against them because we forced them into choosing between servitude and war. How does that make them our enemies?

Comment: They're our enemies because we're fighting against them. Plain and simple. Who cares why we're fighting them; the fact is we're in a war against them. What else should we call them?

Comment: Would you go out to war against your friends?

Comment: How does attacking someone make them less of your enemy than waiting for them to attack you?

Comment: I'm really not following the question or the follow up comment discussion. Your opponent in a war is termed an enemy or foe. I don't know of any other terminology that would be different. Can you edit your question to explain what you are seeking? I'm not the only one who is puzzled. Are you assuming that the only enemies are from the 7 nations?

Comment: @ezra What are you talking about? milhemet reshut has nothing to do with preemptive attack.

Comment: If you like an answer consider marking it accepted. If not, consider clarifying what additional information you want.

Answer (score 1):

Malbim (Deut. 21:10) follows the opinion that it can be a voluntary war. He explains that those they are fighting are called enemies, since although it is a voluntary war, they [presumably] wouldn't wage war against them, were they not already enemies:

> מלת כי יציין את הרשות...ומ"ש על אויביך כי לא תעשה מלחמת הרשות כנגד עמים שאתה בשלום עמהם רק כנגד אויבים

Answer (score -1):

Chazaal say in Masechet Yevomot page 48'2'מפני מנה גרים מעונין ויסורין באין עליהם אחרים אומרים מפני ששהו עצמם להכנב תחת כנפי השכינה that geirim get punished for not coming until now. Since there is no reason that they should not see the truth in judaism ,and especially so when being offered to join or when being in contact with them.Therefore we conclude that it is hate and jealousy which prevented them until now.

The Gemarah in Pesochim page 49'2' says אמר רבי עקיבא כשהייתי עם הארץ אמרתי מי יתן לי תלמיד חכם ואנשכנו כחמור וכו' which clearly illustrates the idea that there was potential in him to become that which he became but it was his hatred and jealousy that prevented him from pursuing this venture.

See what hate came out of Arpah and her children upon her declining the opportunity she had together with Ruth.

Now we have proof of their hatred from that, that they refused to be part of us which would have ended the war.

In regular times when the gentile is living  their way without anything  special occurring we certainly can not draw conclusions from their seemingly ignorance which they have about the true point of the world and in life.

Comment: "and especially so when being offered to join or when being in contact with them" Are you assuming that they were offered to join? Why would you assume this? Why even assume contact?

Comment: "See what hate came out of Arpah and her children upon her declining the opportunity she had together with Ruth." What was that hate? How is it relevant? Are you suggesting that all non-Jews hate Jews and are therefore called enemies? If so, consider clarifying that.

Comment: "Now we have proof of their hatred from that" Huh? Where is the proof of any hatred? All your sourceless claim was, was that non-Jews will be punished for not converting since they are assumed to accept the truth of Judaism. That doesnt say that they hate Jews. Maybe they don't to convert for some other reason.

Comment: Or are you saying that the proof that they are our enemies is that they refuse to let us conquer them (?!) ?